# How to display data in a nscombobox in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscombobox

I have an `NSComboBox` in my mainmenunib file.
I have created an outlet of combobox "*cb*" and made a connection of it with my delegate
I also connected delegate and datasource with my delegate.

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{    arr=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",@"f", nil];
[cb reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfItemsInComboBox:(NSComboBox *)aComboBox{
return arr.count;
}

-(id)comboBox:(NSComboBox *)aComboBox objectValueForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)loc{
return [arr objectAtIndex:loc];
}
```

But when I run the application data is not coming in combobox.
Please help me out as i am new to cocoa programming.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach seems reasonable on the face of it, though using a mutable object as an instance variable is often ill-advised (for reasons wholly unrelated to your issue here, and which we needn't get into at this stage).

There are two things that jump out as possible issues:

1) Are you using ARC?  If not, `arr` is going to disappear from under you because `-arrayWithObjects` returns an autoreleased object and you have nothing retaining it.  If you are using ARC (the default for new project on Lion, I believe), this doesn't apply to you.  Plus I would expect you would crash, not just get no data.

2) More likely, you forgot to `-setUsesDataSource:YES`, which is the flag that tells NSComboBox whether to look at its data source or to use the internal contents approach that @JustinBoo supplied.  I believe this defaults to NO, which would cause your exact problem.  I don't have Interface Builder in front of me at the moment, but IIRC there is a "uses data source" checkbox that you can check to enable this attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can add objects using `-addItemWithObjectValue` to Your `NSComboBox` like this:

```
arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",@"f", nil];

for (int i = 0; i < [arr count]; ++i)
{
    [cb addItemWithObjectValue:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

You can see [NSComboBox Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSComboBox_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Comment: This is *one* way to do it.  The OP seems to be interested in using a data source, however, which is perfectly acceptable (and arguably more flexible).

Comment: Yes, This approach is a simple one.